# Referencing other tables in Google App Engine using db.ReferenceProperty

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I have one model (company category) populated by a table - simple names etc. I then have a company model and I'd like to link these two together such that I have have categories in a populated drop down box.

```
class CompanyCategory(db.Model):
    categoryname = db.StringProperty(required=True) 

class Company(db.Model):
    companyurl = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    companycategory = db.ReferenceProperty(CompanyCategory, collection_name='category')
```

However when I do this I get the following error:

```
<class 'google.appengine.ext.db.DuplicatePropertyError'>: Class CompanyCategory already has property categoryname 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/XXX/1.358759458095086806/showcompanies.py", line 52, in <module>
    class Company(db.Model):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 514, in __init__
    _initialize_properties(cls, name, bases, dct)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 429, in _initialize_properties
    attr.__property_config__(model_class, attr_name)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 3656, in __property_config__
    self.collection_name))
```

How do I make this work? I have looked at some examples, but I'm not able to make work in this case. How can I make the companycategory a list.

Here is what is in the table:

CompanyCategory Entities

```
‹ Prev 20 1-1 Next 20 ›
    ID/Name     categoryname
    id=96001    ss
```

---

This is where the model definition is the other way around. I want each company to have have a category which is populated from a table. With the following definition I can get something that resembles what I am looking for:

```
class CompanyCategory(db.Model):
    categoryname = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s' % (self.categoryname)

class Company(db.Model):
    companyurl = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    companyname = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    companydesc = db.TextProperty(required=False)
    companyaddress = db.PostalAddressProperty(required=False)
    companypostcode = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    companyemail = db.EmailProperty(required=False)
    companycountry = db.StringProperty(required=False)



    companyvalid = db.BooleanProperty()
    companyentrytime = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    companylatlong = db.GeoPtProperty()
    companycategory = db.ReferenceProperty(CompanyCategory)
```

I now get a drop down box when I go to add a company - populated from the values in the table. However I'm not getting the value's in the drop down populated into the text value in the datastore upon submission. How should this be done?

Comment: Are you trying this in the local dev appserver or prod? Using the local dev appserver I'm unable to reproduce your issue. Can you also include the code you use to instantiate Company and CompanyCategory?

Comment: The error says: "Class CompanyCategory already has property categoryname" which seens you are declaring ``categoryname = db.StringProperty(required=True)`` more than once in the ``CompanyCategory`` model.

Comment: @Dan This is straight in production.

Comment: @ChristopherRamírez. I only have this one. The companyCategory is exactly as it was defined above.

Comment: Did you tried to clean existing entities? it could be possible that you have conflicting entities created w/ a previous version of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Pasting your code into [shell.appspot.com](http://shell.appspot.com/) works just fine - so whatever the cause of your problem, your sample code is not representative of it. As Christopher Ramirez suggests, you're probably declaring `companycategory` twice, either in the same model, or in a parent class of the model.